# Passing css styles from React Parent component to its child component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have React parent component **A** which has its own scss file **a-style.scss**. Component **B** is child of A. A is passing **styleInfo** object as props which is applied on B.

My question is - is there any way we can define **styleObj** in a-style.scss instead of defining it inline. I want all styling related info should be in external scss file.

**Component A**

```
import "./a-style.scss";
import B from "./B.js";

class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  const styleObj = {
    backgroundColor: "#F9F9F9",
    borderRadius: '2px',
    color: "#686868",
  };

  render() {
    return (<B styleInfo={this.styleObj}></B>);
  }
}
```

**Component B**

```
class B extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div style={this.props.styleInfo}></div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to define CSS properties based on class in your scss/css. And then pass `className` from `props` in your React component:

```js
class A extends Component {
  theme = "themeA";

  render() {
    return (<B styleInfo={this.theme} />);
  }
}

class B extends Component {      
  styleClass = ["B"];

  render() {
    const className = styleClass.push(this.props.styleInfo).join(' ');
    return (<div className={className} />);
  }
}
```

```css
.themeA {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #686868;
}

.B {
  /* Some style for B component */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just import that one file directly into `B.js`?

Is there any benefit of having it go through a parent, seems like necessary routing to me!

If you do need this, then I would just keep it in JS, as this is what JS is good at, or at least, have JS just do the className switching and, again, just have one css file that is a main style lookup hash!

Best of luck!